# Replacing strings in text files

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to replace some text in a file. I need to change the number in the below string (spacing included):

```
 "2016101901   ; serial number"
```

This number may vary, but the format is always the same (so it may be 2015100101, etc.).

I'm not sure how to approach this using wildcards...  I've tried below and it doesn't work:

```
{$_ -replace "*   ; serial number", "2016101902   ; serial number"}
```

Any ideas how I'd do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-replace` method is using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex). So use this:

```
{$_ -replace '^\d{10}(\s*;\s*serial number)', '2016101902$1'}
```

Comment: Thank you, however there are other strings of numbers in these files I worry would be changed too.  I need to append the first string with the "; serial number" at the end.  It has to match the pattern     NNNNNNNNN   ; serial number